# How can I tell in Linux which process sent my process a signal

Tags: linux, signals

I have a java application that got `SIG TERM`. I want to know the pid of the process that sent this signal.
Is that possible?

Comment: There's a similar question with possibly better answers, depending on your use case. The question is shell focused https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186200/

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Two Linux-specific methods are [`SA_SIGINFO`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) and [`signalfd()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/signalfd.2.html), which allows programs to receive *very* detailed information about signals sent, including the sender's PID.

- Call [`sigaction()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) and pass to it a `struct sigaction` which has the desired signal handler in `sa_sigaction` and the `SA_SIGINFO` flag in `sa_flags` set. With this flag, your signal handler will receive *three* arguments, one of which is a `siginfo_t` structure containing the sender's PID and UID.
- Call [`signalfd()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) and read `signalfd_siginfo` structures from it (usually in some kind of a select/poll loop). The contents will be similar to `siginfo_t`.

Which one to use depends on how your application is written; they probably won't work well outside plain C, and I wouldn't have any hope of getting them work in Java. They are also unportable outside Linux. They also likely are the Very Wrong Way of doing what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The first method mentioned (sigaction/SA_SIGINFO/siginfo_t) is actually a POSIX standard and are supported on Mac OS, FreeBSD, OpenBSD too, not just Linux.

Comment: In case someone was searching for this in terms of having caught a signal under gdb: execute `p $_siginfo`, and then look at `si_pid` field, it is supposed to contain the sending process PID.

Comment: Note that the sender's pid is not always set. Unfortunately, the field `si_pid` is in a union, so when you *think* you are reading the pid you might actually read something completely different. For instance, when your program has a segfault, the `SIGSEGV` signal has no `si_pid`. Whether or not `si_pid` is safe to access is described in `man sigaction`. If you have `si_code == SI_USER || si_code == SI_QUEUE` then `si_pid` is set. Otherwise it gets complicated.

Answer (score 14):

I also needed to identify the signal sender in a program, so I took grawity's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8400532/1052126), and used it in my program, it works well.

Here's the sample code:

**send_signal_raise.c**

```
// send signal to self test - raise()

#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

static int int_count = 0, max_int = 5;
static struct sigaction siga;

static void multi_handler(int sig, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *context) {
    // get pid of sender,
    pid_t sender_pid = siginfo->si_pid;

    if(sig == SIGINT) {
        int_count++;
        printf("INT(%d), from [%d]\n", int_count, (int)sender_pid);
        return;
    } else if(sig == SIGQUIT) {
        printf("Quit, bye, from [%d]\n", (int)sender_pid);
        exit(0);
    }

    return;
}

int raise_test() {
    // print pid
    printf("process [%d] started.\n", (int)getpid());

    // prepare sigaction
    siga.sa_sigaction = *multi_handler;
    siga.sa_flags |= SA_SIGINFO; // get detail info

    // change signal action,
    if(sigaction(SIGINT, &siga, NULL) != 0) {
        printf("error sigaction()");
        return errno;
    }
    if(sigaction(SIGQUIT, &siga, NULL) != 0) {
        printf("error sigaction()");
        return errno;
    }

    // use "ctrl + c" to send SIGINT, and "ctrl + \" to send SIGQUIT,
    int sig;
    while(1) {
        if(int_count < max_int) {
            sig = SIGINT;
        } else {
            sig  = SIGQUIT;
        }
        raise(sig); // send signal to itself,

        sleep(1); // sleep a while, note that: SIGINT will interrupt this, and make program wake up,
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    raise_test();
    return 0;
}
```

***Compile:***

`gcc -pthread -Wall send_signal_raise.c`

**Execute:**

`./a.out`

**What it does:**

The program sends `SIGINT` to itself 10 times, before sending `SIGQUIT` to terminate itself.

Also, during its execution, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to send `SIGINT`, or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> to send `SIGQUIT` which would terminate the program by hand.

The program could successfully identify who sent the signal(s).

Answer (score 2):

[BCC](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc) includes the `killsnoop` utility. It requires a kernel with BPF support.

Excerpt from [killsnoop (8) man-page](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/33c8b1aca84b4cdd955efb14d06cea6ce7db4169/man/man8/killsnoop.8):

```
       killsnoop  traces  the  kill()  syscall, to show signals sent via this method. This may be
       useful to troubleshoot  failing  applications,  where  an  unknown  mechanism  is  sending
       signals.

       This  works by tracing the kernel sys_kill() function using dynamic tracing, and will need
       updating to match any changes to this function.

       This makes use of a Linux 4.5 feature (bpf_perf_event_output()); for  kernels  older  than
       4.5, see the version under tools/old, which uses an older mechanism.

       Since this uses BPF, only the root user can use this tool.
```

Comment: I have a signal (37 (SIGRTMIN+3) ) which is being sent to a process that killsnoop doesn't log. Can there be a signal that doesn't flow through the syscalls that it monitors?

Comment: Seems like `sigqueue` uses a different syscall

Comment: After adding also `sigqueue` to `killsnoop` I still get nothing

Answer (score 0):

No, Signals are not intended as an interprocess communication channel.  As far as I am aware, there is no PID passed.  The sending PID is irrelevant for all of the uses I have seen for signals.  You can be relatively sure that the processes sending the signal either had root privileges, or belonged to the same UID as your process.

It is possible that the process that sent the signal does not exist anymore.  If the kill command was used rather than the shell built-in, it is almost certain the process no longer exists.

From the Java side this is even more difficult.  The process runs in a Java Virtual Machine, which is abstracted from the Operating System.  Not all Operating System concepts exist with this machine.