# Linux C: upon receiving a signal, is it possible to know the PID of the sender?

Tags: c, linux, signals, system, ipc

Suppose my C program handles `SIGUSR1`.

When it receives this signal, is it possible to know who sent it?
I.e., How to get the pid of sender process?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I tell in Linux which process sent my process a signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400530/how-can-i-tell-in-linux-which-process-sent-my-process-a-signal)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, if you use the [`sigaction()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) call to set up your signal handler instead of `signal`. Doing so will let you set up a signal handler that takes three parameters:

- An `int`, for the signal number (just like `signal`)
- A `siginfo_t *`, which is a structure containing all sorts of information about the source of the signal, including the pid of the sender if applicable. (It also includes some information about the cause of the signal for automatic signals like `SIGSEGV`.)
- A `ucontext_t *`, which has to do with which thread got the signal. Mostly ignorable.

Answer (score 11):

Yes. Register your signal handler using `sigaction` with the `SA_SIGINFO` flag, filling in the `sa_sigaction` field. Now your handler function takes a `siginfo_t*` parameter, which includes a field `si_pid`.

Note that `si_pid` is only set under some circumstances. In your case, you'll want to check that check that `si_code` is set to `SI_USER` or `SI_QUEUE`. Read `man 2 sigaction` for more.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is using [`signalfd()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html). If you use signals to send information between processes, then a more structured signal handling than signal handlers is most likely what you want. `struct signalfd_siginfo::ssi_pid` is the sender.

Example from the man page:

```
#include <sys/signalfd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define handle_error(msg) \
    do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    sigset_t mask;
    int sfd;
    struct signalfd_siginfo fdsi;
    ssize_t s;

    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGINT);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGQUIT);

    /* Block signals so that they aren't handled
       according to their default dispositions */

    if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, NULL) == -1)
        handle_error("sigprocmask");

    sfd = signalfd(-1, &mask, 0);
    if (sfd == -1)
        handle_error("signalfd");

    for (;;) {
        s = read(sfd, &fdsi, sizeof(struct signalfd_siginfo));
        if (s != sizeof(struct signalfd_siginfo))
            handle_error("read");

        if (fdsi.ssi_signo == SIGINT) {
            printf("Got SIGINT\n");
        } else if (fdsi.ssi_signo == SIGQUIT) {
            printf("Got SIGQUIT\n");
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        } else {
            printf("Read unexpected signal\n");
        }
    }
}
```

**See also:** [`sigqueue()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigqueue.2.html). Like [`kill()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html), but you can pass an integer or pointer in the same call.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a complete example of the POSIX-standard `sigaction()` API:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void sigusr1(int signo, siginfo_t *si, void *data) {
  (void)signo;
  (void)data;
  printf("Signal %d from pid %lu\n", (int)si->si_signo,
         (unsigned long)si->si_pid);
  exit(0);
}

int main(void) {
  struct sigaction sa;
  memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
  sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
  sa.sa_sigaction = sigusr1;
  if (sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, 0) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", "sigaction", strerror(errno));
  }
  printf("Pid %lu waiting for SIGUSR1\n", (unsigned long)getpid());
  for (;;) {
    sleep(10);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Try to run it and then send it SIGUSR1 (e.g. `kill -SIGUSR1 that-pid` from a shell)

`sigaction` function: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/sigaction.html

`siginfo` structure: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/basedefs/signal.h.html