# How i can debug what sent TERM signal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, sidekiq

How i can found what sent `TERM` signal?

in my `sidekiq` log i see this message within 1 minute interval

```
2016-07-18T16:43:02.090Z 21906 TID-bdwq8 DEBUG: Got TERM signal
2016-07-18T16:43:02.090Z 21906 TID-bdwq8 INFO: Shutting down
2016-07-18T16:43:02.090Z 21906 TID-bdwq8 INFO: Terminating quiet workers
2016-07-18T16:43:02.091Z 21906 TID-1b9tbo INFO: Scheduler exiting...
2016-07-18T16:43:02.591Z 21906 TID-bdwq8 INFO: Pausing to allow workers to finish...
2016-07-18T16:43:03.593Z 21906 TID-bdwq8 INFO: Bye!
```

So i cant run long time worker

May be there is some console command in linux 
which show me periodic  restart of something that affected on sidekiq?

How i can debug it?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is a bit tricky as every process having the proper access rights can send a SIGTERM to your worker.

from within ruby what you can do is to register a trap `Signal.trap`, just not sure how that could be helpful: https://gist.github.com/sauloperez/6592971

it looks like it's quite complicated even on the system level: [How can I tell in Linux which process sent my process a signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400530/how-can-i-tell-in-linux-which-process-sent-my-process-a-signal)