# Linux C programming with signal & process

Tags: linux, process

I want ask How can I get pid and uid of sending process?????

I want make program which use signal.

I made sig_handler which print uid of sending process, pid of sending process.

And by using SIGCHLD I want print uid and pid of sending process.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is similar to others here: see [How can I tell in Linux which process sent my process a signal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8400530/2697122) (and probably others) for Linux-specific details.

If your problem is really about ways processes on Linux can communicate with each other - that is, general interprocess communication (IPC) - there are also lots of resources here on Stackoverflow and elsewhere: [Which Linux IPC technique to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2281204/2697122), among others.